# Silverlight TimePicker CurrentTime

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, timepicker

Is there any way to remove the current time that shows when TimePicker have focus in Silverlight ?

TimePicker :

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

Category :
  Input > TimePicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply re-template the control to remove the popup.

In Blend, add a TimePicker to your page. Right click it and select "Edit Template->Edit a copy...". In the template you will then see a "TimeUpDown" control (shown below the "RootElement" in the "Objects and Timeline" area). Right click a re-template using the same actions ("Edit Template->Edit a copy"). In the template of the TimeUpDown control, simply delete the "TimeHontPopup" control.

Compile, run, select the control and hey-presto, no more "current time" popup.

You can put these templates in a common location for use templating all the TimePicker controls that you want to remove the popup from.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for me was to just use code. Look at my reply here: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/172586/559256.aspx#559256